# Postfix Email tracing, where is it now

Tags: postfix, sendmail, spamassassin

I have searched for an explicit answer to this question and haven't yet found one. I am new to administering Postfix so please forgive my ignorance.

Company A sends out an enormous amount of email on a monthly basis (accounts/statements). These are generated by the software automatically.

Company B is 1 of the many recipients.

Company C appears to be handling their Spam/Mail on their behalf.

The software uses mailx(heirloom) to relay the email via the SMTP server.
This portion took us sometime to iron out, thats another story!

Of approx 2000 emails a proportion of them are appearing to be sent by Postfix, however are not appearing in the recipients mailboxes.

Here is what I have cut out of the maillog to show the transition of the email through our system.

> MAIL VIRUS CHECKING:

```
    Oct  9 12:01:41 mail amavis[6736]: (06736-04) ESMTP::10024 /var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20151009T215931-06736: <something@CompanyA.com> -> <notifyme@CompanyB.com> SIZE=686308 Received: from mail.appl.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.appl.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP for <notifyme@CompanyB.com>; Fri,  9 Oct 2015 22:01:41 +1000 (EST)
    Oct  9 12:01:41 mail amavis[6736]: (06736-04) Checking: n4Wfn4DUYbwx [AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA] <something@CompanyA.com> -> <notifyme@CompanyB.com>
    Oct  9 12:01:41 mail amavis[6736]: (06736-04) Open relay? Nonlocal recips but not originating: notifyme@CompanyB.com
    Oct  9 12:01:42 mail amavis[6736]: (06736-04) FWD via SMTP: <something@CompanyA.com> -> <notifyme@CompanyB.com>,BODY=7BIT 250 2.0.0 Ok, id=06736-04, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 831C6598028
    Oct  9 12:01:42 mail amavis[6736]: (06736-04) Passed CLEAN, [AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA] [AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA] <something@CompanyA.com> -> <notifyme@CompanyB.com>, Message-ID: <5617b7a5.KuBuw1eNziNYOJ5oss1g63mm@CompanyA.com>, mail_id: n4Wfn4DUYbwx, Hits: -1.579, size: 686308, queued_as: 831C6598028, 1661 ms
```

> MAIL PASSED FROM VIRUS CHECKER TO LOCAL SMTP SERVER

```
    Oct  9 12:01:42 mail postfix/smtp[6771]: F3F7C59802D: to=<notifyme@CompanyB.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.8, delays=2.1/0/0/1.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok, id=06736-04, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 831C6598028)
    Oct  9 12:01:42 mail postfix/qmgr[17558]: F3F7C59802D: removed
```

> MAIL QUEUED AND SENT VIA spamfilter.CompanyC.com

```
    Oct  9 12:01:58 mail postfix/smtp[6733]: 831C6598028: to=<notifyme@CompanyB.com>, relay=spamfilter.CompanyC.com[CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC]:25, delay=16, delays=0.23/0.01/14/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E5EF54BEDE0)
    Oct  9 12:01:58 mail postfix/qmgr[17558]: 831C6598028: removed
```

> EMAIL NO LONGER APPEARS TO BE IN OUR SYSTEM

I cannot locate any reference to "831C6598028" in the remainder of the maillog. So I have made the assumption based on "status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E5EF54BEDE0)" that the email has left my system.

I have not had any bounce or reject notifications from CompanyC at this point.

So I have started the process of contacting CompanyC to see if they are blocking it and if so, why.
Could it be that the sending address is blacklisted somewhere?

Is my trace correct?

Have I made any wrong assumptions?

Happy to be guided in the right direction if I have done something wrong.

David

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Though I will note that you [should not obfuscate](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) anything that does not absolutely need to be obfuscated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you've done anything wrong.

The email was queued as E5EF54BEDE0 on spamfilter.CompanyC.com. They've done something with it, the only way to know is to ask them unless you get a bounce.